# Error Deploying Artifact to Github from VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to build maven project in VSTS using hosted agent.
I want to deploy my artifact to github. task i am using is Powershell. i am getting error **"There is no tracking information for the current branch**".
but **artifcat are deploying to github**, But Build Defination is failing.

Comment: You dont provide any information about what you have tried, how shell we know what you need to do different then?

Comment: What's the powershell script to deploy artifacts to github? And do you mean commit the artifacts to a github repo?

Comment: powershell script what i gave in build task.
cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
git init
git config --global user.email "************@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "*********"
git add *.*
git commit -m "updating"
git remote add origin  https://username:password@github.com/username/reponame.git
git pull 
git push --set-upstream origin master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If the github repo is not empty and you want to keep the commit histories**, you can use the script as below:

```
cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
git init
git config --global user.name name
git config --global user.email ***@gmail.com
git add .
git commit -m "update"
git remote add origin https://username:password@github.com/username/reponame -f
git checkout -b temp
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git merge temp -X theirs --allow-unrelated-histories
git push -u origin master
```

**If the github repo is empty or you don’t need to keep the commit histories**, you can use the script as below:

```
cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
git init
git config --global user.name name
git config --global user.email ***@gmail.com
git add .
git commit -m "update"
git remote add origin  https://username:password@github.com/username/reponame -f
git push -f origin master
```

And deselect Fail on Standard Error option:

[image]

Comment: Can you push github repo successful now?